# Trying to figure out how cmath.h calculates the value of Trancedental functions.But function calling seems to be recursive in header files

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I am using Visual Studio 2019.
I have written a bare bones code to calculate and print the value of sine when I enter a number as an argument.
When I right click the call of sin() using math.h and cmath.h as the headers.It first takes me to the defination of sin in the cmath.h header on line 234.Which lookes something like this:

```
_NODISCARD _Check_return_ inline float sin(_In_ float _Xx) noexcept /* strengthened */ {
    return _CSTD sinf(_Xx);
}
```

Now when I right click on the sinf() which is in the return part of the function I am taken to tyhe defination of sine in the corecrt_math.h header.Which looks like this:

```
 _Check_return_ __inline float __CRTDECL sinf(_In_ float _X)
        {
            return (float)sin(_X);
        }
```

And now when I right click on the sin() function it takes me back to the cmath.h header.
This seems very counter intuitive as when I make header files they are accompanied by another header where I declare the functions which are imoplemented in a .cpp files but here there seems to neither be a .cpp file nor another header which implements trencedental functions.

So how does C++ calculate these functions?

Comment: Both definitions are inside large `#if` blocks which do not get compiled at the same time. You could generate the preprocessed file and follow the conditionals in effect to see what gets actually compiled, and/or the assembly file to see what it gets compiled to (likely an intrinsic).

Comment: @dxiv Sir in the header file itself?

Comment: Yes, the conditionals are in the headers, if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is broad, but the answer highlights:

[Argument reduction](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/%7Ephatak/645/supl/Ng-ArgReduction.pdf) to a sub-range like 0 to pi/4.

Evaluating using a [Minimax approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_approximation_algorithm) e.g. a crafted polynomial divided by another polynomial.

Comment: Sir, I can understand your predicament. Sir, I was hoping you could point me to the source code and I could read it on my own .Sir, I have been trying to implement mathematical functions for a while and I have arrived at something called the CORDIC if you could tell me how I can see the code which C++ uses I will be massively indebted.

Comment: Monica Sir this document was amazing this is the culmination of 3 weeks of my study.

Comment: @ShridharSharma C++ does not require a particular trig function implementation.  Could small like `static double my_sin_helper(double xx, double term, unsigned n) {   if (term + 1.0 == 1.0) {     return term;   }   return term - my_sin_helper(xx, xx * term / ((n + 1) * (n + 2)), n + 2);
} // valid for [-pi/2 + pi/2] 
double my_sin_primary(double x) {   return x * my_sin_helper(x * x, 1.0, 1); }`.  It is _implementation defined_.

Comment: Oh I see Yes Yes now I understand why you sent the previous document. @chux-Reinstate Monica

Answer (score 0):

You might be slightly confused because the definition of `sin` can occur within a `namespace std { }`. It may look recursive when `std::sin` calls `::sinf` which in turn calls `::sin`, but this is just a way of making sure all functions give the same results. It's after all the same mathematical sine function.

MSVC has a few implementations, depending on your CPU. These are not C++, but assembly.

Comment: Sir I know you may feel like I am putting the ball in your court but could you please please give me a link to the algorithm and the assembly code. You do not realize how happy you have made me by saying it could be in assembly.

Comment: @ShridharSharma: You can see it yourself in Visual Studio 2019. Write a short program, add a breakpoint before `sin`, switch to the disassembly window and step in. Do this both in debug and release mode, to see the differences.